# Memory management with Photos framework

Tags: ios, swift, image, memory, photos

I'm having memory problems retrieving objects from the Photos framework in iOS. I show you my code :

```
public class func randomImageFromLibrary(
        completion: @escaping (_ error: ImageProviderError?, _ image: UIImage?, _ creationDate: Date?, _ location: CLLocation?) -> Void) {

        // Create the fetch options sorting assets by creation date
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions.init()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "creationDate", ascending: true) ]
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "mediaType == \(PHAssetMediaType.image)")

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

            let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: nil)

            if fetchResult.count == 0 {

                // The restoreAnimationAfterFetching method contains UI changes, this is why
                // we perform this code on the main thread
                Async.main({

                    print("No photos in the library!")

                    completion(.PhotoLibraryEmpty, nil, nil, nil)
                })

                return
            }

            var photos: [PHAsset] = []

            // Enumerate the PHAssets present in the array and move everything to the photos array
            fetchResult.enumerateObjects({ (object: PHAsset, index, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in
                //let asset = object
                photos.append(object)
            })


            let asset = photos[0] // This could be any number, 0 is only a test

            // The options for the image request
            // We want the HQ image, current version (edited or not), async and with the possibility to access the network
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions.init()
            options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.highQualityFormat
            options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersion.current
            options.isSynchronous = false
            options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

            PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(
                for: asset,
                options: options,
                resultHandler: { (imageData: Data?, dataUTI: String?, orientation: UIImageOrientation, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) in

                    // If the image data is not nil, set it into the image view
                    if (imageData != nil) {

                        Async.main({

                            // Get image from the imageData
                            let image = UIImage.init(data: imageData!)

                            completion(nil, image, asset.creationDate, asset.location)
                        })
                    } else {

                        // TODO: Error retrieving the image. Show alert
                        print("There was an error retrieving the image! \n\(info![PHImageErrorKey])")

                        completion(.GenericError, nil, nil, nil)
                    }
                }
            )
            }
        }
```

[Async](https://github.com/duemunk/Async) is a framework to manage easily the `GCD`.
When I call this method I have a heavy memory load. If I call it multiple times I can see `PHAsset` in Instruments that continues to increase without releasing anything. I thought about the `autoreleasepool`, but I'm not sure how to use it correctly. Do you have any suggestion or something like that? Last thing is that I need to use this even in a Today Widget that crashes continuously because of this heavy load of memory.

Comment: I read this once http://nshipster.com/phimagemanager/ . may be it is of some use to you.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I already read that article, interesting, but it doesn't help for this case.

Comment: Try to reduce the possible points of failure. Does the same behavior occur when using GCD directly without the Async framework?

Comment: @xpereta already tried, the same happened. The weird thing is that even after that the image data has been downloaded and displayed as a UIImage object, the memory keep increase (under the voice : "All Heap Allocations")

Comment: PHAsset is a very small object (it doesn't contain the photo or anything like that). So is this really a big deal?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are using the option to make the call to requestImageData asynchronously:

```
isSynchronous = false
```

which you probably do not need because the calling code is already in a background thread.

This also means that the result handler may be called more than once. And in combination with the isNetworkAccessAllowed option may delay the finish of the requests and the release of the PHAsset instances.

Try with:

```
isSynchronous = true
isNetworkAccessAllowed = false
```